# On the global structure of the Gromov-Hausdorff metric space

Tags: gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry

*This is a purely idle question, which emerged during a conversation with a friend about what is (not) known about the space of compact metric spaces. I originally asked this question at math.stackexchange (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356066/global-structure-of-the-gromov-hausdorff-space), but received no answers even after bountying.*

**Background.** If $A, B$ are compact subsets of a metric space $M$, the *Hausdorff distance* between $A$ and $B$ is the worst worst best distance between their points: $$d_H(A, B)=\max\{\sup\{\inf\{d(a, b): b\in B\}: a\in A\}, \sup\{\inf\{d(a, b): a\in A\}: b\in B\}\}.$$ For two compact metric spcaes $X, Y$, their *Gromov-Hausdorff distance* is the infimum (in fact, minimum) over all isometric embeddings of $X, Y$ into $Z$ via $f, g$ of $d_H(f(X), g(Y))$. The Gromov-Hausdorff space $\mathcal{GH}$ is then the "set" of isometry classes of compact metric spaces, with the metric $d_{GH}$.)

**Question.** How homogeneous is $\mathcal{GH}$? For example: while distinct points in $\mathcal{GH}$ are in fact distinguishable in a broad sense, it's not clear that distinct points can always be distinguished just by the metric structure of $\mathcal{GH}$, so it's reasonable to ask:

> Are there any nontrivial self-isometries of $\mathcal{GH}$?

There are of course lots of related questions one can ask (e.g., autohomeomorphisms instead of isometries); I'm happy for any information about the homogeneity of $\mathcal{GH}$.

---

Please feel free to add tags if more are appropriate.

Comment: For any $r>0$, there is an autohomeomorphism of $\mathcal{GH}$ that takes a compact metric space and scales its metric by $r$.

Comment: On the first place: does $d_{GH}$ behaves as a distance? does it satisfy the triangle inequality? is $d(X,Y)>0$ whenever $X,Y$ are non-isometric? (Btw, the Hausdorff distance is for *non-empty* compact subsets, and hence $d_{GH}$ is also for non-empty compact metric spaces only.)

Comment: @EricWofsey yes, for autohomeomorphisms the question should be about (anything approaching a) classification rather than existence.

Comment: @YCor I assume all metric spaces are nonempty as a rule :). Yes, $d_{GH}$ (restricted to the compact spaces!) is a metric, and in particular satisfies the triangle inequality; see e.g. http://www.helsinki.fi/~cristina/pdfs/gromovHausdorff.pdf

Comment: Using the shrinking mentioned by Eric, we see that there is a distinguished point $o$ (the singleton metric space) such that there is a geodesic between any point in GH joining it to $o$ (the distance between any $X$ to $o$ equals the diameter of $X$), and since this shrinking is continuous, we see that $X$ is contractible. Natural questions are whether all other points in $X$ can be joined by geodesics, whether $X$ is locally path connected, locally contractible (in several possible senses), etc.

Comment: The space $\mathcal{GH}$ is known to be geodesic; beyond that, I don't know much.

Comment: Geodesic is a nice property (is there a reference) but this property of having a geodesic retraction to a point by self-similarities is much stronger and quite remarkable, so it would sound natural to ask if this only holds for the point corresponding to the singleton metric space, or for some others. Possibly stupid question: is GH homeomorphic/isometric to some Banach space?

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment to the math.stackexchange question, an isometry of GH must fix the single point space and also the diameter of any space. Furthermore, using similar ideas, it can be shown that the number of points in a space is invariant under isometry in GH. From there, it seems likely that the only isometry is the trivial one.

Comment: @YCor: That the space GH is geodesic is proved in http://arxiv.org/abs/1504.03830. The question of whether GH is homeomorphic to $\ell^2$ is Problem 1062 in [T.Banakh, R.Cauty, M.Zarichnyi, Open problems in infinite-dimensional topology. in: Open Problems in Topology, II (E.Pearl ed.), Elsevier, 2007, p.601–624] electronically available at http://www.franko.lviv.ua/faculty/mechmat/Departments/Topology/banpapers.html.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To answer the main question -- there are no nontrivial self-isometries of $\mathcal{GH}$.

I can give a proof of this, but as it is getting rather long, I will state some facts in $\mathcal{GH}$ without proof for now, and will come back and provide provide proofs or references.

First, a bit of notation. Let ${\rm diam}(A)=\sup\{d(a,b)\colon a,b\in A\}$ denote the diameter of a metric space $A$. For any $\lambda > 0$ use $\lambda A$ to denote the space with the same points as $A$, but with scaled metric given by $d_\lambda(a,b)=\lambda d(a,b)$. Let $\Delta_n$ denote the (n-1)-simplex - a space consisting of $n$ points all at unit distance from each other. So, $\Delta_1$ is the space consisting of a single point, and $\lambda\Delta_n$ is a space consisting of $n$ points all at distance $\lambda$ from each other.

Now, the following are standard,
\begin{align}
&d_{GH}(\Delta_1,A)=\frac12{\rm diam}(A),\\
&d_{GH}(A,B)\le\frac12\max({\rm diam}(A),{\rm diam}(B)),\\
&d_{GH}(\lambda A,\mu A)=\frac12\lvert\lambda-\mu\rvert{\rm diam}(A).
\end{align}
For reference, I am using [*Some Properties of Gromov–Hausdorff Distances*](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00454-012-9406-8) by Fecundo Mémoli for the standard properties of $\mathcal{GH}$. Then, the one-point space $\Delta_1$ is distinguished just in terms of the metric on $\mathcal{GH}$ as follows,

> **1.** $A$ is isometric to $\Delta_1$ if and only if $d_{GH}(B,C)\le\max(d_{GH}(A,B),d_{GH}(A,C))$ for all $B,C\in\mathcal{GH}$.

That this inequality holds for $A=\Delta_1$ follows from the first two standard properties above. On the other hand, if $A$ contains more than one point, so ${\rm diam}(A)>0$, we can take $B=\Delta_1$ and $C=\lambda A$ for any $\lambda > 1$,
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
d_{GH}(B,C)&=&d_{GH}(\Delta_1,\lambda A)=\frac\lambda2{\rm diam}(A) \\
&>&\frac12\max(1,\lambda-1){\rm diam}(A)=\max(d_{GH}(A,B),d_{GH}(A,C))
\end{eqnarray}.
$$
So, statement 1 holds in both directions. Therefore, any isometry fixes $\Delta_1$ and, by the first standard property of $\mathcal{GH}$ above, it preserves the diameter of spaces.

Next, the simplexes $\Delta_n$ are distinguished in terms of the metric as follows,

> **2.** The following are equivalent for any $A\in\mathcal{GH}$.
>
> - ${\rm diam}(A)=1$ and $d_{GH}(B,C)\le\max(d_{GH}(A,B),d_{GH}(A,C))$ for all $B,C\in\mathcal{GH}$ with diameter less than or equal to $1$.
> - $A=\Delta_n$ for some $n\ge2$.

The proof of this is given below. So, an $\iota$ is an isometry on $\mathcal{GH}$ maps the set of simplifies $\{\Delta_n\colon n\ge2\}$ to itself.
Now, the finite spaces in $\mathcal{GH}$ can be identified.

> **3.** For any $n\ge2$ and $A\in\mathcal{GH}$, the following are equivalent.
>
> - $d_{GH}(A,B)=d_{GH}(\Delta_n,B)$ for all $B\in\mathcal{GH}$ with $d_{GH}(\Delta_n,B)={\rm diag}(B)\ge\max({\rm diag}(A),1)$.
> - $A$ is a finite space $n$ or fewer points.

Therefore, if $\mathcal{GH}_n$ denotes the finite metric spaces with $n$ or fewer points, (2) and (3) imply that $\iota$ permutes $\{\mathcal{GH}_n\colon n\ge2\}$. As it must preserve the inclusions $\mathcal{GH}_n\subset\mathcal{GH}_{n+1}$, it follows that $\iota$ maps $\mathcal{GH}_n$ to itself for each $n\ge2$.

Now, fix $n\ge2$, let $N=n(n-1)/2$, and $S$ be the subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$ consisting of points $\mathbf x=(x_{ij})_{1\le i < j\le n}$ with $x_{ij}>0$ and $x_{ik}\le x_{ij}+x_{jk}$ for all distinct $i,j$ (here, I am using $x_{ij}\equiv x_{ji}$ whenever $i > j$. Let $G$ be the group of linear transformations of $\mathbb{R}^N$ mapping $\mathbf x$ to $g_
\sigma(\mathbf x)=(x_{\sigma(i)\sigma(j)})$ for permutations $\sigma\in S_n$. Then, $S$ is a region in $\mathbb{R}^N$ with nonempty interior bounded by a finite set of hyperplanes, and maps in $G$ take the interior of $S$ into itself. We can define $\theta\colon S\to\mathcal{GH}$ by letting $\theta(\mathbf x)$ be the space with $n$ points $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ and $d(a_i,a_j)=x_{ij}$, and define a (continuous multivalued) function $f\colon S\to S$ by $\theta\circ f=\iota\circ\theta$. Then, $\theta$ maps $S$ onto the metric spaces with $n$ points, the values of $f(\mathbf x)$ are orbits of $G$, and the fact that $\iota$ is an isometry means that if $\mathbf y=f(\mathbf x)$ and $\mathbf y^\prime=f(\mathbf x^\prime)$, then $\min_g\lVert g(\mathbf y)-\mathbf y^\prime\rVert=\min_g\lVert g(\mathbf x)-\mathbf x^\prime\rVert$, with the minimum taken over $g\in G$ and using the $\ell_\infty$ norm on $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Now, let $X\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ consist of the fixed points of elements of $G$, which is a finite union of hyperplanes, and $S^\prime=S\setminus\ X$. Note that $f$ maps $S^\prime$ into itself -- suppose that $\mathbf y = f(\mathbf x)\in X$ for some $\mathbf x\in S^\prime$. Then, $g(\mathbf y)=\mathbf y$ for some $g\in G$. Choosing $f(\mathbf x^\prime)=\mathbf y^\prime$ arbitrarily close to $\mathbf y$ with $h(\mathbf y^\prime)\not=\mathbf y^\prime$ (all $h\in G$), we have $\mathbf x^\prime$ and and $g(\mathbf x^\prime)$ arbitrarily close to $\mathbf x$, so $g(\mathbf x)=\mathbf x$, contradicting the assumption.
So, in the neighbourhood of any point in $S^\prime$, we can take a continuous branch of $f$, in which case $f$ is locally an isometry under the $\ell_\infty$ norm, which is only the case if $f(\mathbf x)=P\mathbf x+\mathbf b$ (where $P$ permutes and possibly flips the signs of elements of $\mathbf x$, and $\mathbf b\in\mathbb{R}^N$), with $P$ and $\mathbf b$ constant over each component of $S^\prime$. As $\mathbf x\to 0$, $\theta(\mathbf x)$ tends to $\Delta_1$, from which we see that $\mathbf b=0$.

So, we have $f(\mathbf x)=P\mathbf x$, and as the components of $f(\mathbf x)$ are positive, $P$ is a permutation matrix. In order that $f$ is continuous across the hyperplanes in $X$, we see that $P$ is constant over all of $S^\prime$ (choosing continuous branches of $f$ across each hyperplane). Then, $P^{-1}gP\in G$, for all $g\in G$, as $f$ is invariant under the action of $G$. So, $P$ is in the normalizer of $G$. Now, it can be seen that centraliser of $G$ in the group of permutations (acting on $\mathbb{R}^N$ by permuting the elements) is trivial, which implies that its normaliser is itself ([*Permutation Groups*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1SPjBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA110&lpg=PA110&dq=normalizer%20transitive%20group%20permutations&source=bl&ots=WRQJ8mEbdH&sig=eqvEr6t1lwP_i4-_0saNIx1r9m0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBGoVChMI4v3mkOmBxwIVgbgUCh2E5goG#v=onepage&q&f=false), see the comment preceding Theorem 4.2B). Hence $P\in G$, so $\iota$ acts trivially on the spaces with $n$ points. As the finite spaces are dense in $\mathcal{GH}$, $\iota$ is trivial.

---

I'll now give a proof of statement (2) above, for which the following alternative formulation of the Gromov-Hausdorff distance will be useful. A *correspondence*, $R$, between two sets $A$ and $B$ is a subset of $A\times B$ such that, for each $a\in A$ there exists $b\in B$ such that $(a,b)\in R$ and, for each $b\in B$, there is an $a\in A$ with $(a,b)\in R$. The set of correspondences between $A$ and $B$ is denoted by $\mathcal R(A,B)$. If $A,B$ are metric spaces then the discrepancy of $R$ is,
$$
{\rm dis}(R)=\sup\left\{\lvert d(a_1,a_2)-d(b_1,b_2)\rvert\colon (a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2)\in R\right\}.
$$
The Gromov-Hausdorff distance is the infimum of ${\rm dis}(R)/2$ taken over $R\in\mathcal R(A,B)$.

Now, lets prove (2), starting with the case where $A=\Delta_n$, some $n\ge2$, for which we need to prove
$$
d_{GH}(B,C)\le\max(d_{GH}(\Delta_n,B),d_{GH}(\Delta_n,C))
$$
whenever $B,C$ have diameter bounded by $1$.
As we have, $d_{GH}(B,C)\le1/2$, the required inequality is trivial unless $d_{GH}(\Delta_n,B)$ and $d_{GH}(\Delta_n,C)$ are strictly less than $1/2$, so we suppose that this is the case. Denote the points of $\Delta_n$ by $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n$. If $R\in\mathcal R(\Delta_n,B)$ is such that ${\rm dis}(R)/2 < 1/2$, then letting $B_i$ consist of the points $b\in B$ with $(p_i,b)\in R$, the sets $B_1,\ldots,B_n$ cover $B$. For any $b,b^\prime\in B_i$ then $d(b,b^\prime)=\lvert d(p_i,p_i)-d(b,b^\prime)\rvert\le{\rm dis}(R)$, so the $B_i$ have diameters bounded by ${\rm dis}(R)$. Also, for any $i\not=j$, if $b\in B_i\cap B_j$ then ${\rm dis}(R)\ge\lvert d(p_i,p_j)-d(b,b)\rvert=1$, giving a contradiction. So, the $B_i$ are disjoint sets covering $B$. Similarly, if $S\in\mathcal R(\Delta_n,C)$ has ${\rm dis}(S)/2 < 1/2$ then we can partition $C$ into $n$ sets, $C_i$, of diameter bounded by ${\rm dis}(S)$. Defining $T=\bigcup_{i=1}^n(B_i\times C_i)\in\mathcal R(B,C)$, it can be seen that ${\rm dis}(T)\le\max({\rm dis}(R),{\rm dis}(S))$, from which the required inequality follows.

Now, we prove the converse - if $A$ has diameter $1$ and is not isometric to $\Delta_n$ for any $n$, then we can find spaces $B,C$ of diameter $1$ with $d_{GH}(B,C)=1/2$ and with $d_{GH}(A,B)$, $d_{GH}(A,C)$ strictly less than $1/2$.
I'll consider first the case where $A$ is finite with $m\ge2$ points, so $A=\{a_1,\ldots,a_m\}$. As $A$ is not isometric to $\Delta_m$, there must exist two points separated by less than unit distance. Wlog, take $d(a_{m-1},a_m)=x < 1$. Then, $m > 2$, otherwise $A$ would have diameter $x < 1$. We can define $R\in\mathcal R(A,\Delta_{m-1})$ to be $\{(a_i,p_i)\colon i=1,\ldots,m-1\}\cup\{(a_m,p_{m-1})\}$, which has discrepancy bounded by the max of $\lvert d(a_i,a_j)-1\rvert$ over $i\not=j$ and $d(a_{m-1},a)m)=x$. So, $d_{GH}(A,\Delta_{m-1}) < 1/2$. Next, we can define $R\in\mathcal R(A,\Delta_m)$ to be the collection of pairs $(a_i,p_i)$ for $i=1,\ldots,m$. Its discrepancy is the max of $d(a_i,a_j)-1$ over $i\not=j$, which is strictly less than $1$, so $d_{GH}(A,\Delta_m) < 1/2$. However, $d_{GH}(\Delta_{m-1},\Delta_m)=1/2$, so $B=\Delta_{m-1}$ and $C=\Delta_m$ satisfies the desired properties.

Now, suppose that $A$ is not a finite space. For any $m\ge2$ there exists a collection $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m$ of $m$ distinct points in $A$. Then, by compactness, we can cover $A$ with a finite collection of nonempty sets $A_1,\ldots,A_r$ of diameter bounded by $1/2$. Set $A_{r+i}=\{a_i\}$ for $i=1,\ldots,m$. Let $S=\{s_1,\ldots,s_{m+r}\}$ be the finite space with $d(s_i,s_j)=1$ for $i,j > r$ and with distance $1/2$ between all other pairs of points. The correspondence $R=\bigcup_{i=1}^{m+r}(A_i\times\{s_i\})$ has discrepancy
$$
{\rm dis}(R)=\max\left\{1/2,1-d(a_i,a_j)\colon 1\le i < j\le m\right\} < 1.
$$
So, $S$ is finite with diameter $1$, contains a subset isometric to $\Delta_m$, and $d_{GH}(A,S) < 1/2$.

Now, we can let $B$ be any finite set with diameter $1$ and $d_{GH}(A,B) < 1/2$. If $m$ greater than the number of points in $B$, let $C$ be a finite set with diameter $1$, a subset isometric to $\Delta_m$, and $d_{GH}(A,C) < 1/2$. Then, $d_{GH}(B,C)=1/2$, and satisfies the required properties, proving (2).

Comment: I'll come back and add the proofs of (2) and (3) when I have some time.

Comment: Lets  consider the  map  $\phi$ on $\mathcal{GH}$  with $\phi(X)=$The  hyperspace of  $X$.  However it is  not  surjective  but I wonder if this  is  an isometry?

Answer (score 11):

We have written a text with more details on the proof given by George Lowther. Here one can see the result:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.02100.pdf
However, locally there are many self-isometries, see
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.04484.pdf